# Comparing two csv files and updating a field according to the comparison using awk

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have the following files:

**file1.csv**

```
ID, Name, Address, Phone, Favorite Color/Colors Match
1, Jim, 12 Main,123-456-7890, Blue
2, Kim,11 Bush,987-654-3210, RedGreen
3, Tim,33 Main,111-111-1111,YellowOrange
4, Zim,66 Main,111-555-1111,YellowOrange
```

**file2.csv**

```
ID, Name, Address, Phone, Favorite Color/Colors Match, Blood Type, Left/Right Handed
1, Jon, 122 Main,333-456-7890, Red, A Pos, Right
2, Tom,111 Bush,999-654-3210, RedGreen, A Neg, Right
3, Tam,333 Main,111-222-1111,YellowOrange, O Neg, Left
4, Zam,99 Main,555-555-1111,Blue, A Pos, Left
```

I would like the following output for each file:

**file1.csv**

```
ID, Name, Address, Phone, Favorite Color/Colors Match
1, Jim, 12 Main,123-456-7890, No Match
2, Kim,11 Bush,987-654-3210, Match
3, Tim,33 Main,111-111-1111,Match
 4, Zim,66 Main,111-555-1111,No Match
```

**file2.csv**

```
ID, Name, Address, Phone, Favorite Color/Colors Match, Blood Type, Left/Right Handed
1, Jon, 122 Main,333-456-7890, No Match, A Pos, Right
2, Tom,111 Bush,999-654-3210, Match, A Neg, Right
3, Tam,333 Main,111-222-1111,Match, O Neg, Left
4, Zam,99 Main,555-555-1111,No Match, A Pos, Left
```

Basically, I want to compare one field based on the ID field in two separate files and determine they match or not.

I tried doing this using **awk**:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR {n[$5]=$0} {if ($1 == n[$1] && $5 == n[$5])    
n[$5]="Match"; else $n[5]="No Match";}1' OFS=, file1.csv file2.csv > testfile.csv
```

But I was left with some unexpected results. I am new to the power of awk so any recommendations would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
cat csv.awk

BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}                
FNR==NR {
   a[$1 SUBSEP $5]
   next
}
{
   $5 = (($1 SUBSEP $5) in a)?"Match":"No Match"
}
1
```

Then use it as:

```
awk -f csv.awk file2.csv file1.csv

ID, Name, Address, Phone,Match
1, Jim, 12 Main,123-456-7890,No Match
2, Kim,11 Bush,987-654-3210,Match
3, Tim,33 Main,111-111-1111,Match
4, Zim,66 Main,111-555-1111,No Match
```

and also:

```
awk -f csv.awk file1.csv file2.csv

ID, Name, Address, Phone,Match, Blood Type, Left/Right Handed
1, Jon, 122 Main,333-456-7890,No Match, A Pos, Right
2, Tom,111 Bush,999-654-3210,Match, A Neg, Right
3, Tam,333 Main,111-222-1111,Match, O Neg, Left
4, Zam,99 Main,555-555-1111,No Match, A Pos, Left
```

---

**Update:** If you want to do it a **single awk command** then here it is.

```
cat csv.awk 

BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{
   key = $1 SUBSEP $5 
}
FNR == NR { 
   a[key]
   next
}
FILENAME == ARGV[2] { 
   if (key in a) {
      $5 = "Match"
      b[key]
   }
   else
      $5 = "No Match"
   print > "_" ARGV[2]
   next
}
{
   $5 = (key in b)?"Match":"No Match"
   print > "_" ARGV[3]
}
```

Then execute it as:

```
awk -f csv.awk file2.csv file1.csv file2.csv &&
mv _file1.csv file1.csv &&
mv _filw2.csv file2.csv
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is awk -f csv.awk file2.csv file1.csv in your first example doing?

Comment: `awk -f csv.awk file2.csv file1.csv` is generating your desired output for `file1.csv` whereas `awk -f csv.awk file1.csv file2.csv` is generating output for `file2.csv`

Comment: Not really, but I think it may have to do with my original files (this was example data here). For some reason awk can't seem to figure out the fields correctly and only appends the result as opposed to replacing.

Comment: That is not awk's fault. That could be due to your different file format. An answer can only work with the details and data provided in question and for that I believe this answer works fine.

Comment: Right. My apologies. I cannot share the data here. Thank you though. I believe your solution should work fine once I figure out what teh issue is with my own files.

Comment: Yep. It was my file. Had the fields switched. Works great now. Thanks!